# PICKIT3 on ubuntu

Tags: hardware, programming

I am kind of a beginner in ubuntu. Does anybody know a way to program  PIC with PICkIT3 on ubuntu? Because I don't want to go back and forth to windows since I got mikroc and proteus working.
thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PICkit 3 is compatible with Ubuntu, and also compatible with the latest MPLAB X ide available here http://www.microchip.com/mplab/mplab-x-ide